# Clear last ROW Cells data when btnDell was clicked

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, tablerow

I have a table with dynamic rows(show/hide). When I click on btnDell my last visible row is hided, but their data are there ..

**This is content for my first row :**

```
//Row1 Cells Controls
        Label rowNo = new Label();
        rowNo.Text = "1-";
        TextBox txt11 = new TextBox();
        txt11.Height = 19;
        TextBox txt12 = new TextBox();
        txt12.Height = 19;
        TextBox txt13 = new TextBox();
        txt13.Height = 19;
        DateTimeControl dt11 = new DateTimeControl();
        dt11.DateOnly = true;
        DateTimeControl dt12 = new DateTimeControl();
        dt12.DateOnly = true;

        tRow1 = new TableRow();
        tRow1.Visible = true;

        TableCell tCellZero = new TableCell();
        tCellZero.Controls.Add(rowNo);
        tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellZero);

        TableCell tCellOne = new TableCell();
        tCellOne.Controls.Add(txt11);
        tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellOne);

        TableCell tCellTwo = new TableCell();
        tCellTwo.Controls.Add(dt11);
        tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellTwo);

        TableCell tCellThree = new TableCell();
        tCellThree.Controls.Add(dt12);
        tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellThree);

        TableCell tCellFour = new TableCell();
        tCellFour.Controls.Add(txt12);
        tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellFour);

        TableCell tCellFive = new TableCell();
        tCellFive.Controls.Add(txt13);
        tRow1.Cells.Add(tCellFive);

        myTbl.Rows.Add(tRow1);
```

[image]

**This is my code for hide last visible row in Table.**

```
    void btnDell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myTbl.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Count(row => row.Visible) > 2)
        {
            myTbl.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Last(row => row.Visible).Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

**How to access cells TextBox.Text and DateTimeControls.SelectedDate ?**

```
myTbl.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Last(row => row.Visible).Cells[1].Text = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Inside your If statement....

```
            var tableRow = Table1.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Last(row => row.Visible);

            foreach (TableCell item in tableRow.Cells)
            {
                foreach (Control cntrl in item.Controls)
                {
                    if (cntrl.GetType() == typeof(DateTimeControl)) 
                    {
                        ((DateTimeControl)cntrl).ClearSelection();
                    }
                    if (cntrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)) 
                    {
                        ((TextBox)cntrl).Text = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: How to check in all visible rows --> cell[0] with if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRoute.Text.Trim())) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833927/asp-net-how-to-check-in-all-visible-rows-cells-for-string-isnullorempty-and-i

Answer (score 2):

And this one?

```
((DateTimeControl)myTbl.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Last(row => row.Visible).Cells[1].Controls[0]).ClearSelection();
```

Comment: I will now try and tell whether it happened