# How to check in all visible rows CELLs for string.IsNullOrEmpty and IsDateEmpty

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a table with rows where I show/hide with button click event. I want to check for my all visible rows with cell index for string.IsNullOrEmpty and IsDateEmpty. **How to do this?**

[image]

**The following code(for check visible cell[0] TextBox) not working:**

```
var allVisibleRows = myTbl.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Where(row => row.Visible);
bool anyTextBoxEmpty = allVisibleRows.Any(row => string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text));
//DestinavionValidation
if (anyTextBoxEmpty)
{
    return "Please, insert a TEXT";
}
```

**The following code(for check second Cell [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMi5h.png) DateTimeControl) not working:**

```
bool anyDateTimeOneValid = allVisibleRows.Any(row => !(((DateTimeControl)row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).IsValid);
bool anyDateTimeOneEmpty = allVisibleRows.Any(row => (((DateTimeControl)row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).IsDateEmpty);
//Date Validation
if (anyDateTimeOneValid || anyDateTimeOneEmpty)
{
    return "Please, insert a Date!";
}
```

**This is following error**

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) at Lirex.WayBillModule.b__2f(TableRow row) at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below if will work, it will check for empty text box on all visible row, just modify to check for the other control type.

```
        var tableRows = Table1.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Where(row => row.Visible);

        bool hasEmptyField = false;
        foreach (var row in tableRows.Where(row => row.Cells.Cast<TableCell>()
            .SelectMany(
                item => item.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                    .Where(cntrl => cntrl.GetType() == typeof (TextBox)))
            .Any(cntrl => string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox) cntrl).Text))))
        {
            hasEmptyField = true;
            break;
        }

        if (hasEmptyField)
        {
            //Do what you want...
        }
```

Edited the answer. Last query was only checking the last visible row. Made some changes and now using the WHERE clause instead of LAST in getting the visible rows.. Changes also include loop for each row.

Below is the original code I posted checking for the LAST visible row only.

```
        var tableRow = Table1.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Last(row => row.Visible);
        var hasEmptyTextBox =
            tableRow.Cells.Cast<TableCell>()
                .SelectMany(
                    item => item.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                        .Where(cntrl => cntrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)))
                .Any(cntrl => string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)cntrl).Text));
```

Comment: just change the IsNullorEmpty to IsNullorWhiteSpace for your requirement.

Comment: Or just forget the foreach loop and query directly in the tableRows.. The foreach condition with minor adjustment will return true or false. pattern it like what I did for hasEmptyTextBox part. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

By using this line `(). All(row => row.Visible);` you are fetching visible properties of all rows, not the rows as you expected. So use like following to select rows

```
var tableRow = myTbl.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Where(row => row.Visible);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.All` returns a `bool`, you want all visible rows so use `Where`:

```
var allVisibleRows = myTbl.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Where(row => row.Visible);
```

You now want to check if there's any empty `TextBox` in the first cell:

```
bool anyTextBoxEmpty =  allVisibleRows
    .Any(r => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((TextBox)r.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text));
```